# File transfer from PC to USB disk is very slow

Tags: 11.04, usb, 64-bit

file transfer from PC to USB disk is very slow in my ubuntu 11.04(64bit) but the vice versa is not.transfer starts with like, for the transfer of 700MB file it starts with 30mb/s and towards the end it stops at 0s and stays put for like 3-4 mins to transfer the last bit. any help to solve this welcome

Answer (score 3):

I assume your usb drive is formatted in fat32. Formatting your usb drive in ext3 or ntfs format will solve speed problem. *But if you connect your ext3 formatted USB drive in another computer running windows, it will not work.*

Answer (score 2):

It is not a answer, and maybe is unrelated, but cheap USB Sticks are slow to write. When the OS is copying to the USB devices it starts fast because it is using main memory as a kind of write cache, but when it runs out of cache the speed decreases enormously.

Maybe, when its stop at 0s, the USB is still dumping all the cached data that it was not transfered yet.

Externals Hard Disk are usually faster and have a internal cache too, so this effect is not as appreciable as with usb memory.